# ADSError: target machine not found Missing ADS routes (7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plc, twincat, twincat-ads

I am have two Windows10 machines with TwinCAT3 in common LAN.
Use pyads for reading and writing vars.

```
import pyads

plc = pyads.Connection('192.168.137.1.1.1', pyads.PORT_TC3PLC1)
plc.open()
plc.read_by_name('GVL.var1')
```

[My ADS ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPkPG.png)
IP addres: 192.168.137.1

Reading and writing on local PC working. But if try running script on second PC(IP 192.168.137.123) have error: ADSError: target machine not found    Missing ADS routes (7).
Computers ping from either side.

Will I be able to connect to the PLC(with TwinCAT3) via ADS if TwinCAT is not installed on the Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an AMS-route between the two hosts. You have to create an AMS-route between the ADS-client and the ADS-server.

Read the [documentation from PyAds](https://pyads.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/routing.html) and the [documentation from Beckhoff](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_system/html/TcSysMgr_AddRouteDialog.htm&id=).